# question about geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the gem 'geocoder'.
I am trying to make an object that will fetch the latitude and longitude from ip address.

This is how my object's model looks like:

```
class Hey < ActiveRecord::Base

  geocoded_by :ip
  after_validation :geocode

  def ip
    return request.ip
  end

end
```

When I create an object I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `request'for #<Hey:0x7f268f47dd00>):
```

if I change the method ip to:

```
  def ip
    return "24.193.83.1"
  end
```

it works. Why does `request.ip` doesn't work in the model ?
`request.ip` works for me in the controller.

How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Oded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

the model:

```
class Hey < ActiveRecord::Base

      attr_accessor :ip_address

      geocoded_by :ip_address
      after_validation :geocode

    end
```

controller:

```
class HeysController < ApplicationController

 def create
        hey = Hey.new
        hey.ip_address = request.ip
        hey.save

        redirect_to :action => "index"
      end

 end
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to store ip of this object. Fill ip_address with request.ip when create new object. Than code in the model will looks like:

```
geocoded_by :ip_address,
  :latitude => :lat, :longitude => :lon #this is also fields in the db
after_validation :geocode
```

or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'store the ip' ? Should I create an attribute in the db called 'ip_address' ?

Comment: yes i mean this, geocoder needs to fetch ip from db or something like this. sorry for my english :] Return "some_ip" works, because it's returning a string that fits well for geocoder. You cant call request.ip method from the model. Request inaccessible from the model layer. So you need to save user ip somewhere before.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I solved it in a different way (using attr_accesor).

Comment: @Oded Harth could you update your answer as the accepted answer please?